# Creating a Java enum

Tags: java, enumeration

I am told I need to create an enumeration Team with 2 values of Varsity and JV.  Is this what it should look like?  Do I need the constructor?

```
public enum Team {
   Varsity, JV;

   private String Level;

    private Team(String studentLevel) {
        Level = studentLevel;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some questions for consideration (and response): Does your code compile?  What is the meaning and purpose of the `Level`/`studentLevel` string? What will it be used for?

Comment: Could I just us this:    
public enum Team {
 Varsity, JV;

}

Comment: Since I don't know what that string will or will not be used for I can't say for certain. That will compile and is valid code. If you don't need the field in the enum values then yes.

Answer (score 3):

It's almost correct: you need to pass values to the constructors, e.g. like this:

```
public enum Team {
 Varsity("level_v"), JV("level_jv");

  private String Level;

  private Team(String studentLevel) {
    Level = studentLevel;
  }
}
```

Whether you need the constructor or not depends on whether your enum needs parameters/fields. You'd then set those fields with the constructor and since they shouldn't be changed in most cases, I'd declare them to be final as well, i.e. `private final String level`.

Comment: Im told I just need one enumeration with the 2 values Varsity and JV, so could I just use this?

Comment: public enum Team {
 Varsity, JV;

}

Comment: @user3586248 if you don't need the `level` field, then yes. That's about the most basic definition of an enum.

Comment: But then there is another class that uses a constructor like this:  
public Student(int ID, Team Level, float GPA) {

Do I need to include Level in the enumeration?

Comment: @user3586248 I don't get it: what does the parameter name `Level` (violates the naming conventions btw) have to do with some field `level` inside your enum? - It might indicate that your enum's name would actually have to be `Level` instead of `Team`. Why is the enum called `Team` anyways (the enum values don't mean anything to me)?

Comment: By convention, Java `enum` names are in upper-case, so `public enum Team { VARSITY, JV; } `.

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Team 
{
Varsity("someLvl"), JV("someLvl");

private String studentLevel;

Team(String studentLevel)
{
    this.setStudentLevel(studentLevel);
}

public String getStudentLevel() {
    return studentLevel;
}

private void setStudentLevel(String studentLevel) {
    this.studentLevel = studentLevel;
}
}
```

You need to set the student level right away.